# How to get RSS in Pidgin (Windows)

Tags: rss, pidgin

I would like to get some rss feeds directly into pidgin chat window.
If you know any way how I could achive this, let me know.

XMPP is not a solution, as it is blocked on my network.

But anything else?

EDIT: 
I know about https://github.com/hrj/feedgin/ - but anybody got that running yet?
Pidgin-Wiki says it only works on Linux.

Comment: Do you even know if Pidgin supports anything other then a XMPP to do this?  If it doesn't then there isn't much you can do.  You could always design your own solution.

Comment: Well there are plenty of supported protocolls. And I don't know about all of them. Also, I don't know about all pidgin plugins. I can tell you that: If there is something for linux, then it's likely to get smth for windows. Maybe someone knows something, that I didn't think of ;)